# python: use decorator to check type of input

Tags: python

I want to use decorator to check the type of input. The decorator is:

```
def inputAssert(*ty_args, **ty_kwargs):
    def decorate(func):
        print('input assert')
        # Map function argument names to supplied types
        sig = signature(func)
        bound_types = sig.bind_partial(*ty_args, **ty_kwargs).arguments
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            bound_values = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
            for name, value in bound_values.arguments.items():
                if name in bound_types:
                    if not isinstance(value, bound_types[name]):
                        raise TypeError(
                            'Argument {} must be {}'.format(name, bound_types[name])
                            )
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorate
```

And it work great for function. But, if I use it in class, something stranger happen.

My code is:

```
from functools import wraps
from inspect import signature


def inputAssert(*ty_args, **ty_kwargs):
    def decorate(func):
        print('input assert')
        # Map function argument names to supplied types
        sig = signature(func)
        bound_types = sig.bind_partial(*ty_args, **ty_kwargs).arguments
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            bound_values = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
            for name, value in bound_values.arguments.items():
                if name in bound_types:
                    if not isinstance(value, bound_types[name]):
                        raise TypeError(
                            'Argument {} must be {}'.format(name, bound_types[name])
                            )
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorate

class Demo:
    @inputAssert(name=str)
    def __init__(self, name=''):
        print('base model init')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('------ base model init start----')
    d = Demo(name='xx')
    print('------ base model init finish----')
```

I print something in `inputAssert`. In my opinion, the printed information should be:

```
------ base model init start----
input assert
base model init
------ base model init finish----
```

However, the actually information is:

```
input assert
------ base model init start----
base model init
------ base model init finish----
```

It make me confused. Why the `inputAssert` is not called for `Demo(name='xx')`?

Comment: Your `print()` statement is in the decorator function itself, so it's executed as soon as the `Demo` class's `__init__` method is defined.  You would want to put it in the wrapper function.

Comment: decorator `inputAssert` is executed when it loads code with class - before it runs `if __name__ == '__main__':` - so it prints it before `base model init start`

Comment: Thank you very much~~~@Iguananaut, @furas